# GLTF Exporter Lighting Issue

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

Just swapped from the older GLTF Blender exporter to the newer import/export version. Upon doing so, my meshes got significantly darker, and I can't figure out why.

mesh lighting sample :

[image]

The left is the older Blender > GLTF exporter, and the right is the newer one. Gamma is set to true, and I've played around with various options within Blender, as well as three.js lighting intensity, etc. (jacking the intensity up to make it look reasonable makes the shadows disappear). It renders the same in Mccurdy's GLTF viewer, and none of the lighting sliders get anywhere close to the lighting from the prior GLTF exporter. I need to use the new version for animation and morph playback purposes. Thanks as always for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it's helpful to anyone else, apparently the newer Blender > GLTF exporter defaulted to THREE.MeshStandardMaterial. I swapped to THREE.MeshLambertMaterial and the problem was solved.

```
            const oldMat = child.material;
            const newMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                color: oldMat.color, 
                map: oldMat.map
            });
            child.material = newMat;
```

Comment: Hm, I'm surprised this fixed the issue. I don't think there was ever a version of the glTF Blender exporter that created Lambert materials... What about setting `material.roughness = 1` – does that help? If not, could you file an issue on the exporter?

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, the exporter created a THREE.MeshStandard material by default. In my .js script I forced a substitution of the standard material using the code snippet above in a for loop inside my loader function.

Comment: Try toggling the textures encoding to sRGB instead of Linear?

Comment: Hi, and thanks. If you mean setting the color ramp inside of Blender to RGB mode, I tried that but didn't see any difference. I'll play around a bit more, but at least the approach above gets me back to where I was...

Comment: MeshStandard seems to be the default in the loader code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e8145dcaa83f57da82a3d3d413c89e34b9f01571/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js#L2300